Taylor Expansion on an Integral
In an article I am using for my dissertation I found a very weird "trivial" affirmation. Supposing that L is a symmetric density function they take as obvious the following equality stating it is obtained by using Taylor Expansions. There are not other hypothesis stated rather than the smoothness of $f$. Could somebody help me with the proof? I have tried several ideas but I am unable to get the expression on the right side.
\begin{equation}
 \int w(t)^{-1} L^{(2)} \left(\frac{y-t}{h} \right) f(t) dt 
 = \frac{1}{\int w(x) f(x) dx} \left( h^3 f^{(2)}(y) + \frac{1}{6} h^5 \left( \int u^2 L^{(2)} (u) \int (1-t)^3 f^{(4)}(y - hut)dtdu \right)  \right)
\end{equation}
I am looking at the proof of Theorem 3.1 here: https://minerva.usc.es/xmlui/bitstream/handle/10347/20313/2017_BorrajoGarciaetal_LengthBiasedData.pdf;jsessionid=462D19EE9EE2C3F12B1C21951CDDF369?sequence=1
They assume w(y) = y but they also stated in the conclusion that it can be generalized for a bounded and a squared integrable function $w$.

Where can we refer the article to? Also, what is the region of integration?

Hello @HugdeRoda! Thank you for showing interest. Both $w$ and $f$ are function defined in $(0, +\infty)$ and positive on all their support. In fact, $f$ is a density with all that means.  This is the article https://minerva.usc.es/xmlui/bitstream/handle/10347/20313/2017_BorrajoGarciaetal_LengthBiasedData.pdf;jsessionid=462D19EE9EE2C3F12B1C21951CDDF369?sequence=1. I am having a look at the proof of Theorem 3.1
